# Проблема с Date на Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

При создании экземпляра Date (new Date()), судя по документации, возвращается текущее локальное время, но мне возвращается время со сдвигом на -2 часа.

Так же при передачи формата даты в виде "dd.mm.yyyy" в конструктор, дата парсится не корректно, возвращается в виде: mm.dd.yyyy.

Пример:

```js
let date = new Date(); // return time === 16:52;
console.log(date); 

// dd.mm.yyyy
date = new Date('12.11.2020')

console.log(date.getDate());
// Метод getDate() возвращает день.
```

Comment: Вы забываете про часовые пояса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, тут у вас две проблемы.

1. Дата в Node.js учитывает локальный временной пояс, однако не все форматы вывода даты этот пояс учитывают. По умолчанию в консоль дата выводится в формате [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), который всегда в "нулевом" часовом поясе (UTC). Браузеры могут выводить дату в консоль по умолчанию в другом формате, отсюда может быть разница. Если вам нужна унификация, всегда пользуйтесь каким-то одним явным методом класса Date для превращения в строку.
2. Создания даты с использованием строки [не рекомендуется](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string) из-за непредсказуемости реализаций. По крайней мере стоит использовать [стандартизированную строку](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format). Ваша строка нестандартна, и тут в дело вступают опять-таки [непредсказуемые алгоритмы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Fall-back_to_implementation-specific_date_formats).